# Where to draw the line in scientific papers in respect to definitions

Tags: notation

Now, a science paper about i.e. "the decrease of sunken pirateships as a function" would look (despite the title) very silly if it would define addition, multiplication, heck even exponentiation or logarithm.

But the problem is, from a studied persons point of view, maybe all "standard stuff" seems silly to define in a science paper.

But if you think this further, then at some point the experts talk in a language which is indistinguishable from cryptic gibberish in the eyes of a normal person.

Also from country to country, heck even from professor to professor in the same college, the notations vary.

So would it be useful to define every operation before you use it in a scientific text?

Comment: Try rigorously defining each element in the statement $1+1=2$ and you'll see why this wouldn't work.  For reference, see *Principia Mathematica* by Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell, where the basics of mathematics are built up from set theory.  In it they aren't able to get around to actually proving that $1+1=2$ until page $362$.

Comment: The question is too broad to answer here. I suggest that you look at the more recent papers you are citing, and look at the papers published in your target journal, to see which terms they define and which they use without defining them. If you err either way, no big deal, the referees and editors will have their say.

Comment: @bof edited it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to answer your basic question, at what level should you give definitions, is to consider your audience.  Are you writing a talk for high school students, a lecture for college students, a paper for something like "Math Monthly", or a paper for an advance math journal?  The answer would be different for each or those.

As for "Also from country to country, heck even from professor to professor in the same college, the notations vary", **standard** notations do not.  If you have some special notation, then, yes, of course, define it.

Comment: ...but then people have different standards; witness for instance the different interpretations of an unembellished $\log$, where different fields' conventions differ by a constant of proportionality. Witness also some people that prefer to use $\mathrm{tg}$ over $\tan$, and ${}_n C_r$ over $\binom{n}{r}$... the list goes on.

Comment: my personal favorite is $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ which are used for the same a lot, while having the "same" difference as = and $\leq$